# Custom post type cannot access child page

Tags: custom-post-types

I have the following custom custom post type, but it does not work. I want it to run with the following URL: `example.com/cartoon-series/post-parent/watch/`

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {
    remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv', 'episodes', 'normal' );
} );
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box( 'episodes-parent', 'Cartoon Series', 'episodes_attributes_meta_box',
        'episodes', 'side', 'default' );
} );

add_action( 'init', function(){
    $labels = array(
        "name" => "Cartoon Series",
        "singular_name" => "Cartoon Series",
        "menu_name" => "Cartoon Series",
        "all_items" => "All Cartoon Series",
        "add_new" => "Add New",
        "add_new_item" => "Add New Cartoon Series",
        "edit" => "Edit",
        "edit_item" => "Edit Cartoon Series",
        "new_item" => "New Cartoon Series",
        "view" => "View",
        "view_item" => "View Cartoon Series",
        "search_items" => "Search Cartoon Series",
        "not_found" => "No Cartoon Series Found",
        "not_found_in_trash" => "No Cartoon Series Found in Trash",
        "parent" => "Parent Cartoon Series",
    );

    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
         "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "cartoon-series", "with_front" => false ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "revisions", "thumbnail" )
    );

    register_post_type( "cartoon-series", $args );

    $labels = array(
        "name" => "Episodes",
        "singular_name" => "Episode",
    );

    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "episodes", "with_front" => false ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "revisions", "thumbnail" )
    );

    register_post_type( "episodes", $args );

} );

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box( 'episodes-parent', 'Cartoon Series', 'episodes_attributes_meta_box',
        'episodes', 'side', 'default' );
} );

function episodes_attributes_meta_box( $post ) {
    $pages = wp_dropdown_pages( array( 
        'post_type' => 'cartoon-series', 
        'selected' => $post->post_parent, 
        'name' => 'parent_id', 
        'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'), 
        'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 
        'echo' => 0
    ) );
    if ( ! empty( $pages ) ) {
        echo $pages;
    } // end empty pages check
}

// 3. Rewrite rule - teach WordPress to parse the custom URL pattern
function pwatch_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^cartoon-series/([^/]+)/watch/?',
        'index.php?episodes=$matches[1]-watch', 
        'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'pwatch_rewrite_rule' );

add_filter( 'post_type_link', function( $post_link,$link ) {
    if ( 'episodes' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        //Lets go to get the parent cartoon-series name
            $parent = get_post( $post->post_parent );
            $post_link = get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/cartoon-series/' . 
                $parent->post_name . '/watch/';
    }
    return $post_link;
}, 1, 4 );
```

Comment: Is it necessary for `cartoon-series` to be hierarchical? That might be causing a conflict. `var_dump($wp_query);` in your 404 template to see what WordPress is trying to query for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'page-attributes' to 'supports' in your arguments for registering the custom post type.